# Meteor onRendered function and access to Collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

When user refresh a certain page, I want to set some initial values from the mongoDB database.

I tried using the onRendered method, which in the documentation states will run when the template that it is run on is inserted into the DOM. However, the database is not available at that instance?

When I try to access the database from the function:

```
Template.scienceMC.onRendered(function() {
    var currentRad = radiationCollection.find().fetch()[0].rad;
}
```

I get the following error messages:

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'rad' of undefined
```

However, when I run the line `radiationCollection.find().fetch()[0].rad;` in the console I can access the value?

How can I make sure that the copy of the mongoDB is available?

Comment: are you using iron-router?

Comment: @Billybobbonnet yes, I have the router package added and use it to direct http to templates only at the moment.

Comment: @ArashSaidi you need to either `waitOn` your data or guard it. I explain these techniques in detail in [this post](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards).

Comment: @David Weldon, should he, if he plans to guard his data, wrap his query in a tracker `autorun ` function? Because guarding will avoid the error on renderding, but will it re-run once the data is available?

Comment: Yeah this one is tricky to directly answer because the data is read in `onRendered` and I don't know how it's being used. Probably an `autorun` is the correct answer, but then again there could be something flawed in leading him in that direction w/o knowing more about the use case. A `waitOn` is the easy answer here but that relies on IR and may or may not be the right UX.

Comment: Ok. Again, thanks for sharing

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, the waitOn function worked. I will provide my own solution as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for me was to use the waitOn function in the router. Thanks to @David Weldon for the tip.

```
Router.route('/templateName', {
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('collectionName');
    },
    action: function () {
        // render all templates and regions for this route
        this.render();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a proper publication (it seems you did) and subscribe in the route parameters. If you want to make sure that you effectively *have* your data in the `onRendered` function, you need to add an extra step.

Here is an example of how to make it in your route definition:

```
this.templateController = RouteController.extend({
    template: "YourTemplate",

    action: function() {
        if(this.isReady()) { this.render(); } else { this.render("yourTemplate"); this.render("loading");}
        /*ACTION_FUNCTION*/
    },

    isReady: function() {


        var subs = [
            Meteor.subscribe("yoursubscription1"),
            Meteor.subscribe("yoursubscription2")
        ];
        var ready = true;
        _.each(subs, function(sub) {
            if(!sub.ready())
                ready = false;
        });
        return ready;
    },   
    data: function() {
        return {
            params: this.params || {}, //if you have params
            yourData: radiationCollection.find()
        };
    }
});
```

In this example you get,in the `onRendered` function, your data both using `this.data.yourData` or `radiationCollection.find()`

**EDIT**: as @David Weldon stated in comment, you could also use an easier alternative: [waitOn](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial)

Comment: This seems rather much in order to just get access to data I am already subscribing to? I hope there is a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: I am not sure to get what you're meaning. Besides your publication, in your route options, you can load the template only if your subscriptions are up and ready. This way, you get the data when your template is rendered. Why do you think it isn't elegant?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your collection, so I can't guarantee that *rad* is a key in your collection, that said I believe your problem is that you collection isn't available yet. As @David Weldon says, you need to guard or wait on your subscription to be available (remember it has to load).

What I do in ironrouter is this:

```
data:function(){
    var currentRad = radiationCollection.find().fetch()[0].rad;
    if (typeof currentRad != 'undefined') {
        // if typeof currentRad is not undefined
        return currentRad;
    }
}
```